# Calling python function with an unknown number of arguments

Tags: python, arguments

I am writing a little script in which I call itertools.product like so:

```
for p in  product(list1,list2,list3):
            self.createFile(p)
```

Is there a way for me to call this function without knowing in advance how many lists to include?

Thanks

Comment: This is not the same question as how to "Unpack a list in Python". Unpacking a list is the *answer* to this question, not the *question*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the star or splat operator (it has a few names):  `for p in product(*lists)` where `lists` is a tuple or list of things you want to pass.

```
def func(a,b):
    print (a,b)

args=(1,2)
func(*args)
```

You can do a similar thing when defining a function to allow it to accept a variable number of arguments:

```
def func2(*args): #unpacking
   print(args)  #args is a tuple

func2(1,2)  #prints (1, 2)
```

And of course, you can combine the splat operator with the variable number of arguments:

```
args = (1,2,3)
func2(*args) #prints (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the splat operator(`*`) to pass and collect unknown number of arguments positional arguments.

```
def func(*args):
   pass

lis = [1,2,3,4,5]
func(*lis)
```