# How can I unpack a list or tuple in place in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Is it possible to unpack a list or tuple such that the values can be used as function parameters?  I.e., how can I make the second line work?

```
f(1,2,3)
f(???([1,2,3]))
```

I'm currently doing this by hand, something like:

```
tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 = [1,2,3]
f(tmp1,tmp2,tmp3)
```

context: I don't have the ability to modify f(), but this is part of a code generator so funky solutions are not a problem.

Comment: @NullUserException: That's for the function signatures. The syntax looks the same, but it is not the same functionality.

Comment: @NullUserException: That is not to say this question is not a dupe, just not of the one you proposed.

Comment: @Martijn I am pretty sure this has been asked before though. I'm on mobile so it's hard for me to look it up

Comment: I've got a bunch of dupes ... But it's hard to really pick which one ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/14565032/748858 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/11973028/748858 , etc.

Comment: @mgilson: Time to stick to one and close everything else as dupes?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Works for me.  you have a preference?  The title of the one proposed by alko seems most clear and the question is probably posed the best (most general/widely applicable).  The answer is OK, but It seems to me that it could use more explanation ... :/

Comment: I'd discuss this in the [Python room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). :-)

Comment: The use of the "in-place" in the title is missleading into this construct: a,*b = [1,2,3]  Please remove it.replace it with "in function-arguments"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `*args` (splat) syntax:

```
f(*[1, 2, 3])
```

See the [call expressions documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls).

There is a keyword-parameter equivalent too, using two stars:

```
kwargs = {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'ham'}
f(**kwargs)
```

and there is equivalent syntax for specifying catch-all arguments in a function signature:

```
def func(*args, **kw):
    # args now holds positional arguments, kw keyword arguments
```